# Changing textContent using javascript, Cushy CMS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

OK, I'm going to get a bad rep here for asking too many questions. I have some javascript that dynamically changes content on my page. This works just fine. My issue is that I need to be able to tag all text with 'class="CushyCms"' in order to allow access to the site owner for easy content changes. Here is the basic code for the script, there is more than just the one set but this will give you an idea of what I'm doing. I tried adding the class tag inside the innerHTML, but Cushy couldn't see it.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function changeText(idElement) {
    if(idElement==0){
      document.getElementById('tagmain').innerHTML ='<class="cushycms">Default text to display on page load.';
      document.getElementById('tagtext').innerHTML ='<class="cushycms">More default body text on page load.';
   }
</script>
```

I am looking for a way to put these text fields in a hidden div and pull the textContent from there. This is an example of a section that works with Cushy

```
 <h2 class="cushycms">Preventative Maintanence</h2>
```

I'm beginning to get the hang of javascript, though Java is my primary language. I want to be more rounded i my langauge skills so I am trying to leanr as much as I can. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I dont get exactly what you want. you want to add a class to the elements you geht by `getElementById`?

Comment: no I am trying to change content, which works, but I need to tag the text with the class for cushy so it can be edited through the cushycms interface.

Comment: to clarify a little. I have the two elements, tagmain and tagtext, the textContent of these elements is changed dynamically using a javascript function in response to a click. What I want is to have the text that is to be inserted into those elements accessible for editing via cushy.

Comment: Cushy doesn't see it because it grabs and parses the HTML over FTP. JavaScript is never executed on the code that Cushy sees.

Answer (score 0):

Cushy CMS requires an actual HTML in order to edit. You could use the following:

#### HTML

```
<p id="tagmain-replace" class="cushycms" style="display:none;"></p>
<p id="tagmain">Default Text</p>
```

#### JS

```
var newText = document.getElementById('tagmain-replace').innerText;
if( newText != ''){
    document.getElementById('tagmain').innerText = newText;
}
```

I would suggest changing the IDs to better work with your project.

Comment: I think that may be what I was looking for. I'll get it setup and let you know. Thanks again.